# MapServer Clustering GetFeatureInfo

Tags: openlayers-2, postgis, mapserver

I'm having a bit of a problem with clustering in map server the clustering itself works fine and the GetFeatureInfo works fine most of the time. However some times when I click on a cluster point it some times gives a different number to how many points are meant to be in the cluster.

See this example cluster should contain 171 points but clicking on it gives 173.

[image: Cluster Incorrect]

Here is my mapfile I've removed the classes as its ridiculously long with them and I don't think its relevant

```
MAP
  FONTSET "fonts.list"
  IMAGETYPE "png"
  MAXSIZE 3000
  NAME "TEST"
  SIZE 1000 1000
  STATUS ON
  UNITS DD

  OUTPUTFORMAT
    NAME "png"
    MIMETYPE "image/png"
    DRIVER "AGG/PNG"
    EXTENSION "png"
    IMAGEMODE RGB
    TRANSPARENT FALSE
  END # OUTPUTFORMAT

  SYMBOL
    NAME "circle"
    TYPE ELLIPSE
    FILLED TRUE
    POINTS
      1 1
    END
  END

  PROJECTION
    "init=epsg:4326"
  END # PROJECTION
  LEGEND
    KEYSIZE 20 10
    KEYSPACING 5 5
    LABEL
      SIZE MEDIUM
      OFFSET 0 0
      SHADOWSIZE 1 1
      TYPE BITMAP
    END # LABEL
    STATUS OFF
  END # LEGEND

  QUERYMAP
    SIZE -1 -1
    STATUS OFF
    STYLE HILITE
  END # QUERYMAP

  SCALEBAR
    INTERVALS 4
    LABEL
      SIZE MEDIUM
      OFFSET 0 0
      SHADOWSIZE 1 1
      TYPE BITMAP
    END # LABEL
    SIZE 200 3
    STATUS OFF
    UNITS MILES
  END # SCALEBAR

  WEB
    METADATA
      "wms_srs" "EPSG:900913"
      "ows_enable_request"  "*"
      "wms_title"   "Testing"
    END # METADATA
  END # WEB

  LAYER
    CLASSITEM "Cluster:FeatureCount"
    CLUSTER
      BUFFER 10
      REGION "ellipse"
    END # CLUSTER
    CONNECTION ""
    CONNECTIONTYPE POSTGIS
    DATA "position from data"
    LABELCACHE OFF
    LABELITEM "Cluster:FeatureCount"
    METADATA
      "wms_include_items"   "all"
      "wms_timeitem"    "datetime"
      "wms_timeextent"  "1910-01-01/2050-02-01"
      "gml_include_items"   "all"
      "gml_geometries"  "none"
      "wms_title"   "Data"
    END # METADATA
    NAME "test1"
    PROCESSING "GETSHAPE_STYLE_ITEMS=all"
    PROCESSING "LABEL_NO_CLIP=True"
    PROCESSING "CLUSTER_GET_ALL_SHAPES=ON"
    PROCESSING "ITEMS=id"
    STATUS OFF
    TEMPLATE "blank.html"
    TILEITEM "location"
    TOLERANCE 10
    TYPE POINT
    UNITS METERS


    CLASSES_HERE
  END # LAYER

END # MAP
```

I hope that provides enough for some suggestions on the issues if any more information is required please do let me know, any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Could it be that you are picking up more than one cluster, for example a cluster of 2 that is hiding beneath the cluster of 171.  What happens if you reduce the TOLERANCE value to 1?